# Breaking out of select for no reason

Tags: c, sockets, select-function

I am doing something like this

```
val = select(max_fd+1,&readfd,0,0,0);
if(val >=1){
    printf("I have got some value");
}
```

My code breaks out of select for no reason. It receives no packet. On 10 runs , I get 1 run where it waits on select. Rest it just quits.

Socket has been set up to receive ICMP packets. On that 1 run, it works perfectly. Why is this crapping out 9 times?

Comment: What platform and implementation of select are you using?

Comment: We can't know that reason. check `errno`.

Comment: Their is no error here. It breaks out of select, but when I loop through the FD's using FD_ISSET, I get nothing. I double checked if the FD's were set correctly.

Comment: I am running on a linux system ,and i dont understand what you mean by implementation of select

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your file descriptor is closed during the process. In this case `val` will be -1 and `errno` wil be set to `EBADF`.

Comment: No the problem is val is set as 1 even when their is no packet

Comment: Please show us how you set `max_fd`, `read_fd` and the test with `FD_ISSET`

Answer (score 0):

`select()` returns -1 if there is some error.
Please check return value of `select()`, and check `errno` if the return value is -1.

Comment: it is returning 1 even when their is no packet